# Can't get text with text box when it is readonly?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a text box

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="checkIn" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true">
</asp:textbox>
```

The text in the text box is inputted through a Jquery DatePicker. In some code behind I am getting the text from this text box like so.

```
string x=checkIn.Text;
```

Why can I not pull the inputted date from the text box? I am guessing it is to do with the fact that it is readonly as when I remove this it works?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, if you specify readonly = "true" you cannot edit the control right, you will not be allowed to choose a value at all.

Comment: but can copy the read only value..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ASP.Net, if the readonly value is changed, it will revert to the original value on the postback.

You can use a wrokaround however, instead of specifying `readonly` declaratively, assign it as an attribute in code-behind. i.e.

instead of

`<asp:textbox runat="server" id="checkIn" ReadOnly="true"...`

apply this is code-behind

`checkIn.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");`

But, the viewstate still may not work with this.

**More info:**

There is a subtle difference between `readonly` and `disabled` controls in HTML. The `disabled` ones will not be submitted with the form, however the `readonly` ones will. Literally, `readonly` is just *readonly*, but `disabled` is actually *disabled*.

From W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

(*Get down to section 17.13.2 Successful controls under 17.13 Form submission*)

ASP.Net however, reverts to the original value on postback if a control is declared like that i.e. if the attribute is set during init. Which is why setting the attribute later (in page load) will not affect this behavior.

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't think a read-only control on the browser would return it's value via the GET or POST... independent of how you set the flag via ASP.NET

Comment: @freefaller `ReadOnly` will be sent on form submission. `Disabled` will not. From W3C Specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Comment: Good call, abhitalks, I wasn't aware of that... I assumed read-only and disabled worked in the same way.  Will remove my question to stop any confusion

Comment: Thanks for this.  This definitely had me scratching my head.  Good old ASP.NET -- confusing developers just for the fun of it!

Answer (score 2):

### Use HTML input tag instead of asp:textbox

**Use this:-**

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" runat="server" id="checkIn" clientidmode="Static"/>
```

**Instead of this:-**

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="checkIn" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: You can add the readonly="readonly" to an asp:textbox via inline css style or class as well.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following code in your code behind file, for asp.net .cs or class file and for vb in .vb file.

You will have to write it on page load event, depending on if you want it before postback or after or irrespective of both...

textbox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `readonly` to false before posting the values through jQuery or Java-Script. It should work.

```
 $('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');
```

Suppose I have a `asp:button` then on client click I need to call a function which remove the read-only attribute from the text-box.

```
<asp:Button ID="MessageButton" runat="server" Text="Hellow"
     OnClientClick="return changeAttribute()" />
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="checkIn" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true">
</asp:textbox>
```

and change attribute function in javascript as follows

```
function changeAttribute()
{
      $('#checkIn').removeAttr('readonly');
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also leave the readOnly attribute off in the asp:TextBox control and use jquery $('#textbox').attr('readOnly','readOnly').

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the value of a readonly textbox if it is within the form.

```
var text = Page.Request.Form[TextBox.UniqueID];
```

Sorry this response is a few years late!

Answer (score 0):

Apply in asp.cs Page :      AttrName.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

Request.Form[txtText.UniqueID]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jQuery, however fixed with a trick:

```
 $('#txtBoxID').removeAttr('readonly');
/// Do your stuff here..

 $('#txtBoxID').add('readonly');
```

;)