# Unable to read from a disabled/readonly textbox - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are two textboxes - txtUrl, txtUrllist. When user types in txtUrl (say abc), the txtUrllist is autofilled with abc.com,abc.eu,..etc using Javascript.

When the txtUrllist is set to `Enabled=false or Readonly = true`, the auto fill works but the text is not being read in code behind. It shows empty. The txtUrl should not be editable by user. What can be done here

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUrllist" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" enabled="false">
</asp:TextBox>



private void GetValues()
 {
   string url = txtUrl.Text;
   string urlList = txtUrllist.Text; // it is empty when Enabled=false or 
                                     //   Readonly = true
 }
```

I also tried enclosing txturllist inside a disabled asp:panel

Comment: If property is disabled, why need read them? User whatever can't change it.
If this change dynamically use hidden-field.

Comment: Why dont you use a label instead of a disabled textbox ?

Comment: Please follow this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565009/cant-get-text-with-text-box-when-it-is-readonly